# Changing CSS with jQuery position

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, position

How do I get the buttons (var selectSlide) to have a different background color if the slider (#mySlider) is at a certain position or with it's corresponding slide.

I have the following jQuery:

```
var slideWidth = $('#mySliderContainer').width();
var selectSlide = $('.selection')

function currentButton() {

  if ($('#mySlider').position().left == 0) {
    selectSlide.eq(0).css('background', '#6F6F6F');
  } else {
    selectSlide.eq(0).css('background', '#D6D6D6');
  }
  if ($('#mySlider').position().left == -slideWidth) {
    selectSlide.eq(1).css('background', '#6F6F6F');
  } else {
    selectSlide.eq(1).css('background', '#D6D6D6');
  }
  if ($('#mySlider').position().left == -slideWidth * 2) {
    selectSlide.eq(2).css('background', '#6F6F6F');
  } else {
    selectSlide.eq(2).css('background', '#D6D6D6');
  }
  if ($('#mySlider').position().left == -slideWidth * 3) {
    selectSlide.eq(3).css('background', '#6F6F6F');
  } else {
    selectSlide.eq(3).css('background', '#D6D6D6');
  }

}
```

The link to the jQuery is located on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwierzba/uhtxtnks/)

Do I need to call the function again within the jQuery for this to work? I may be overlooking something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are checking the left position while the animation is moving it, so it won't match up.

A possible solution would be to keep track of your active slide in a variable that gets updated separately.

Moving the slides left and right can have code like:

```
activeSlide = (activeSlide+1) % slideCountWidth;
```

and

```
activeSlide = (activeSlide-1) % slideCountWidth;
```

That handle the wrapping. Directly clicking the slides can directly set the current slide to whatever was clicked.

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uhtxtnks/50/